# NumberFormatException in Android

Tags: java, android, numberformatexception

I'm making an application in which the user can add Store departments and for those departments the ability to add the cities of where the departments are located.

I keep on getting a NumberFormatException when I'm trying to add a city for a departement:

```
Caused by: java.lang.NumberFormatException: Invalid long: "null"
            at java.lang.Long.invalidLong(Long.java:124)
            at java.lang.Long.parseLong(Long.java:345)
            at java.lang.Long.parseLong(Long.java:321)
            at org.hello.addgroups.vestiging_list.onCreate(vestiging_list.java:45)
```

after this the app crashes but when I restart the app the values are added into the list.

these are my classes:
Add_vestiging.java:

```
public class Add_vestiging extends Activity implements View.OnClickListener{

EditText et,hiddenet;
Button add_bt, cancel_btn;
SQLController dbcon;
Intent i;
Long groupd;

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.add_new_vestiging);
    et = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.vestigingName);
    add_bt = (Button) findViewById(R.id.addBtn);
    cancel_btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.cancelBtn);

    dbcon = new SQLController(this);
    try {
        dbcon.open();
    } catch(SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    i = getIntent();
    String id = i.getStringExtra("groupID");
    groupd = Long.parseLong(id);
    add_bt.setOnClickListener(this);
    cancel_btn.setOnClickListener(this);
}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
        switch(v.getId()) {
            case R.id.addBtn:
                String name = et.getText().toString();
                try {
                    dbcon.insertVestiging(groupd, name);
                }catch(SQLiteException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                Intent main = new Intent(Add_vestiging.this, vestiging_list.class);
                startActivity(main);
                break;
            case R.id.cancelBtn:
                super.finish();
                break;

        }
}
}
```

vestiging_list.java:

```
public class vestiging_list extends Activity {

        ListView lv;
        SQLController dbcon;
        TextView title;
        Button addves;
        Long long_id;
        String groupid;
        Intent add_ves;
        String groupname;
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
                super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
                setContentView(R.layout.vestiging_list);
                dbcon = new SQLController(this);
                title = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.vestitel);


                try {
                        dbcon.open();
                } catch (SQLException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                }
                add_ves = getIntent();
                groupid = add_ves.getStringExtra("groupID");
                groupname = add_ves.getStringExtra("groupName");
                title.setText(groupname);
                long_id = Long.parseLong(groupid);

                addves = (Button)findViewById(R.id.addves_bt_id);
                lv = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.vestigingList_id);

                addves.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(View v) {

                                add_ves = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Add_vestiging.class);
                                add_ves.putExtra("groupID", groupid);
                                startActivity(add_ves);
                        }
                });

                Cursor cursor = dbcon.readVestigingen(long_id);
                String[] from = new String[] { GroupDatabaseHelper.V_ID, GroupDatabaseHelper.VESNAME};
                int[] to = new int [] { R.id.vesID, R.id.vesName};

                SimpleCursorAdapter adapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(vestiging_list.this, R.layout.vestiging_single_row_item, cursor, from, to,1);
                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                lv.setAdapter(adapter);

                     }
}
```

Any ideas on how to remove the NumberFormatException?
Any help is greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: debug and check what is being passed as parameter in parseLong() method.

Comment: The correct question is: how to remove null in this place.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Any ideas on how to remove the NumberFormatException?

The exception is caused by Long.parseLong in `vestiging_list` at line 45. The reason is that `groupid`, in your case in `null`. Since you didn't fill up the `Intent` object you used to start  `vestiging_list`.

E.g.

```
case R.id.addBtn:
      String name = et.getText().toString();
      try {
         dbcon.insertVestiging(groupd, name);
       }catch(SQLiteException e) {
          e.printStackTrace();
       }
    Intent main = new Intent(Add_vestiging.this, vestiging_list.class);
    main.putExtra("groupID", String.valueOf(groupd));
    startActivity(main);
    break;
```

assuming that `groupd` is a long.

Answer (score 0):

I think problem is in the following line :

```
 int[] to = new int [] { R.id.vesID, R.id.vesName};
```

What is the type of "R.id.vesName" ?. It should be integer.

Answer (score 0):

From the stack trace that you have provided I can assume that groupId is null:

```
groupid = add_ves.getStringExtra("groupID");
...
long_id = Long.parseLong(groupid);
```

According to the Long's [Javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Long.html#parseLong%28java.lang.String%29) Long#parseLong(String) throws an Exception if the argument is not a parsable Long, sth which is the case with null.

Check if groupid can be null else you have a bug. If it can be null then check if it equals null and then set long_id to an appropriate value e.g. 0 or -1.

Answer (score 0):

It looks to me like you're creating an Intent, but you're not passing the info to the intent. The class reference to the current class is just a trace, and doesn't include info.

When you make the Intent in the Add_vestiging class, in onClick, do something like main.putExtra("groupID", id).

Looks like you're putting it in the SQLController, so you could try passing that as well.